# Loading Iron Ruby DSL files on demand

Tags: .net, ruby, dsl, iron

Currently I have an application that stores metadata information written in a boo internal DSL.

I store the metadata in seperate .boo files that I load if and when I need them like this:

IConfigReader reader = factory.Create(BUILD_FILE_NAME);

I would like to take advantage of Iron Ruby's or indeed Ruby's meta programming by converting the boo DSL into Iron Ruby.

First of all, is it possible to load a Ruby file in this way and secondly, can I return a data structure from the DLR to the CLR.

I really nope this make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.  See:  http://www.ironruby.net/Documentation/Hosting_Ruby_in_.NET